# Why is $\mathbb{C}_p$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

I know that two closed fields of caracteristic $0$ and uncountable are isomorphic iff they have the same cardinality. But I don't know why $\mathbb{C}_p$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{C}$. Can anyone give me some reference or hint ?

Comment: By $C$, do you mean $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Step 1: Any complete metric space without isolated points has cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$ (continuum cardinality).  I got a nice explanation of this [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22830/improvements-of-the-baire-category-theorem-under-not-ch).  In particular $\mathbb{C}_p$ has cardinality at least $\mathfrak{c}$.

Step 2: [As wikipedia knows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Cardinality), a topological space which is Hausdorff, first countable and separable (so in particular a separable metric space) has cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$: indeed, every point is the limit of a sequence from a countable set, and $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$.  Now $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is dense in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ (a consequence of Krasner's Lemma: see e.g. $\S 3.5$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter3.pdf)) and hence also
in its completion $\mathbb{C}_p$.  So $\mathbb{C}_p$ has cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$.

[**Added**: Here is alternate -- less elegant but more elementary -- argument for Step 2:
(i) For any infinite field $K$, the cardinality of $K$ is equal to the cardinality of its algebraic closure.
(ii) For any metric space $X$, the cardinality of the completion of $X$ is at most
$\# X^{\aleph_0}$ (the number of sequences with values in $X$).  By standard facts on cardinal exponentation, we have $\# X \leq \mathfrak{c} \iff \# X^{\aleph_0} \leq \mathfrak{c}$.]

Thus by the [Schroder-Bernstein Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schroder-Bernstein_theorem), $\mathbb{C}_p$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: You need a separation assumption (Hausdorff, say) in step 2. Of course, we have that in this case.

Comment: @Chris: I sure do, thanks.

Comment: Step 1 also has an elementary version : using $p$-adic Hensel expansion, we see that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is uncountable (which is very similar to what can be done in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Joel: that's definitely another nice way to see Step 1, thanks.  (I'm not sure whether it's more or less elementary than what I said; it depends on the person, I suppose.)